# How to know the actual type of a call expression, or whether the expression is partially applied

Tags: f#, f#-compiler-services

I'm experimenting with creating a linter for F#, using FSharp.Compiler.Service. I'm trying to implement a check for missing `use` for `IDisposable` values.

It should (among many other cases) trigger on this:

```ml
let x = System.IO.File.OpenText ""
```

But not this (since `OpenText` is not actually called):

```ml
let x = System.IO.File.OpenText
```

In the typed tree for these code snippets, I can easily find information about the *full* types of `x` and `OpenText` (`string -> _`), but seemingly no information about the actual type of the expression `System.IO.File.OpenText` (without an argument applied), nor whether all parameters are applied to `OpenText`. I am also having trouble finding this information in the untyped AST, not to mention associating expressions in the typed tree with those in the untyped tree.

How can I find out the actual type of an expression (and not just the function used in an expression)? Or alternatively, how can I find out in this case whether a function is actually called or partially applied?